# RetainCount for View Controllers in TabBarController -(aka releasing a tabBarController)

Tags: iphone

I have created an iPhone app where you start in a NavController and after a couple of levels you select an option from the table and an animated view pops in that has a tabbarcontroller at its root.

This is a completely seperate view that replaces the navcontroller.  You tab around and when you want to go back to the options screen you press back and another animated transition plays swapping back the navigation controller removing the tab bar controller and releasing it.

The problem comes with releasing the UITabBarController.  If you press the tab buttons to switch between tabs it seems you continually increase the reference count for the view controllers.  Then when you call release on the tabBarController reference it will only release the view controller of the selected tab or any tabs you haven't viewed yet, and it takes one of the retain count on the others tabs viewcontrollers.  This means you leak all your Model objects, custom cell objects etc from each of the other tabs that were not selected.

As an example of what I am seeing, if you create a new template TabBarController project in xcode and add a viewWillAppear method to the first view controller that prints out the retain count for itself.  Start the app and press back and forth on the First and Second tab buttons and watch the log the retain count just keeps increasing.

So I am wondering if there is a way to release a tab bar controller and have it release all of its view controllers at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

If this is true, it's a bug, and you should file a report on Apple Radar.

Answer (score 0):

Just for completeness, I did post this problem in the apple dev forums looking for some confirmation but never heard anything back.

Checking out my app on OS3.0 shows that this behaviour is now fixed.  Reference counts never go increase and releasing the UITabBarController appears to work.

Sadly I put a nasty hack in to fix this which doesn't play well with OS 3.0 so it's now conditional compilation time.